Array value disappears after if statement - Pinescript
I'm encountering an issue where an array value assigned within an "if" statement seems to disappear in subsequent candles.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
var myArray = array.new_float(30)

if myCondition
    array.set(myArray, 3, myValue)

plot(array.get(myArray, 3))

In this code, myCondition is a boolean condition that is only true for a single candle. The array value is correctly assigned when myCondition is true, but it disappears in the next candle where myCondition is false.
I've checked that the array size remains the same and there are no other references to modify the array. I'm expecting the array value to persist even after the condition is no longer true.
Can anyone explain why this might be happening and how I can fix it? Thank you!
